# Magnific Popup interfering with my Ajax cart slider, my coding won't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify, cart

Basically I have an Ajax cart slider - slides from right to left when item is added to cart. I have an option for customers to add a product with an image to their cart, I offer them to view the image directly from cart, by clicking "view image" hyperlink, which triggers magnific popup.

[image: Cart view]

However problem comes when they click away from the picture (when its loaded), I want to make it work so it only closes the picture (when clicked away), not Ajax cart as well. I have located the code which triggers Ajax cart to close when clicked away:

`

```
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#cart-notification').length && !$(event.target).closest('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').length){
      if($('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("aria-expanded") == "true" && $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("imgshow") == "false") {
        $("#cart-notification").removeClass("active");
        $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("aria-expanded","false");
      }
    }
```

`

So it seems pretty simple, I decided to add an attribute to the cart-notification class named "imgshow". If they click on "view image" in cart, it sets imgshow to "true" (when magnific pop up is triggered), otherwise it's set to "false" by default (so the above code can work). In case aria-expanded is "true" and imgshow is "false", ajax cart gets closed when clicked away from the screen/ajax cart slider. So I set this code, which gives imgshow "true" value when viewed from cart (so the ajax cart wouldn't close when clicked away):

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imagepopup').magnificPopup({
                callbacks: {
                open: function(){
                   $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("imgshow","true");
                },
                close: function(){
                   $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("imgshow","false");
                }
            },
    type:'image'});
});
```

`

Everything is working fine, all attributes are changing as they should, but for some reason, the script just doesn't function. But it doesn't work only when magnific popup window is active. If I for example change "imgshow" value to "true" when the magnific pop up is not active, Ajax cart slider won't close. But when these same values are present when magnific pop up is active, the first script block above just ignores my callbacks.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? I can't wrap my head around it. Only thing I can think of is because it creates a whole new div class when magnific pop up is active, but doesn't make too much sense as why that would mess with my script block.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found solution if anyone needs it ever. Seems like you need to delay "close" function, otherwise it all "reveals" in one go.
Basically this did the job:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imagepopup').magnificPopup({
                callbacks: {
                open: function(){
                   $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("aria-expanded","false");
                },
                close: function (){
                  setTimeout(function(){
                   $('[data-href="#cart-notification"]').attr("aria-expanded","true");  
                                       }, 500);
                }
            },
    type:'image'});
});
```